# delete template fragment cache from view

Tags: django, django-templates

In template I have code like this one:

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}
    .. sidebar for logged in user ..
{% endcache %}
```

Now from a view I need to delete this particular fragment, so based on the id 'sidebar' with arg request.user.username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django template fragment caching is a bit over rated. And it leads to problems like what you have just run into, having to invalidate a cache from time to time. For that there exists [make_template_fragment_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)

> django.core.cache.utils.make_template_fragment_key(fragment_name,
>   vary_on=None)   If you want to obtain the cache key used for a cached
>   fragment, you can use make_template_fragment_key. fragment_name is the
>   same as second argument to the cache template tag; vary_on is a list
>   of all additional arguments passed to the tag. This function can be
>   useful for invalidating or overwriting a cached item

The following example is adapted from the docs

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

key = make_template_fragment_key('sidebar', [request.user.username])
cache.delete(key) # invalidates cached template fragment
```

Comment: Thanks i'm investigating this but adding the 2 imports as in your example raises: "raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty." The key is set, not sure why I get this, i read it could be a circular import problem.

Comment: that has nothing to do with your current question or my answer it's something to do with you settings file. May i suggest that you post a separate question on it

Comment: Indeed it was unrelated and your answer works fine thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project